# Unable to enter the blank form textarea after $().html();

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am writing a footnote like SO's comment,

the template:

```
<div class="col-md-12 add-article-footnote">
    <a href="{% url 'article:footnote_create'%}">add a footnote</a>
</div>
```

the script:
when "add a footnote" is clicked, it prompts an footnote form,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.add-article-footnote').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $addArticleFootnote = $(".add-article-footnote");
    var footnoteForm = `
<br class="cbt">
<form action="" class="footnote-form">
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="footnote" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="footnoteBtn">Add Annotation</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>`;
    $addArticleFootnote.html(footnoteForm);
});//click event
})
```

However,when the form is emerged, I cannot click into the blank textarea,but could enter in with right click,

If I click instantly, the vertical bar flashed in the beginning of the line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert the form into the `.add-article-footnote` element. The same element which triggers your jQuery function every time. That means, even if your form is there, the jQuery function is triggered again, the form gets reinitialized and you can´t click on it.

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-article-footnote', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('form-active')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $addArticleFootnote = $(".add-article-footnote");
    $addArticleFootnote.addClass('form-active');
    var footnoteForm = `
     <br class="cbt">
     <form action="" class="footnote-form">
     <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-md-9">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="footnote" rows="3"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" id="footnoteBtn">Add Annotation</button>
     </div>
     </div>
     </form>`;
    $addArticleFootnote.html(footnoteForm);
  }
});
```

So when you add the form to the page you add the class `form-active` to the `add-article-footnote` element and then you check if it already has that class before the function gets executed. If true you don´t do the function again. Another possibility would be to delete the `add-article-footnote` element on click and insert the form to its parent element.